# Configuring ear web module in Wildfly

Tags: jakarta-ee, jboss, wildfly, ear, wildfly-8

I am migrating a legacy Java EE web application from orion server to WildFly. 
The directory structure of the ear file is as below:
my_proj.ear
  |--META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
  |--META-INF/application.xml
  |--web/a_few_js/jsp_files
  |--web/WEB-INF/classes/a_few_java_classes
  |--web/WEB-INF/web.xml

The application.xml has the following:

```
<application>
    <display-name>my_proj</display-name>
    <module>
    <web>
        <web-uri>web</web-uri>
    </web>
    </module>
</application>
```

I am able to deploy the ear successfully in JBoss. However, when I hit the url "localhost:8080/my_proj", I get a 404.

I am able to hit the URLs for war files based deployment without any issues. Am I missing anything here?

I am relatively new to Java EE and JBoss.

Please let me know if you need any additional information.

Comment: To continue with my work, I've decided to repackage it as war. I am not sure why the legacy application was packaged as .ear to begin with. Thanks everyone for the answers. Still interested in knowing the solution to the above question.

Answer (score 1):

You configured web-uri as **web** and then try address http://localhost:8080/web if port is right.

Comment: Hi Alexander, the web-uri element in application.xml is to point the web component inside the ear. It's is not the context root.

Comment: You have a mistake. In EAR context root of web application defines through application.xml in META-INF folder in ear root.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add a jboss-web.xml in the WEB-INF dir.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web PUBLIC "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd" "http://www.jboss.org/j2ee/dtd/jboss-web_5_0.dtd">
<jboss-web>
    <context-root>my_proj</context-root>
</jboss-web>
```

Your web.xml version should be version 3:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">
```

Comment: ozOli, I tried adding context root through jboss-web.xml as well as application.xml(as mentioned below). It didn't help either way.